# Dual of the algebra of endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of arbitrary dimension. I'm supposed to prove that the isomorphism

> $\text{End}(V) \to \text{End}(V)^*$ is canonical.

To start with, I am not even sure what this map should look like.
I know how to identify elements of a vector space with its dual, but this identification is non-canonical.
I'm not sure how replacing a vector space with its algebra of endomorphisms makes this identification canonical.

One other approach I can think of is using the isomorphism $\text{End}(V) \cong V \otimes V^*$ and working from there, but I still cannot figure out a map, let alone how it would be canonical.

Comment: there is only a canonical isomorphishm $\text{End}(V)\cong V\otimes V^*$  when $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Good point. Then I'm even more lost on how to define this map here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They won't even have the same dimension unless $V$ is finite-dimensional. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, there is a canonical isomorphism, which abstractly is given by the composite of the sequence of isomorphisms

$$\text{End}(V) \cong V \otimes V^{\ast} \cong (V \otimes V^{\ast})^{\ast} \cong \text{End}(V)^{\ast}$$

(where we use in the middle the natural isomorphism $(V \otimes W)^{\ast} \cong W^{\ast} \otimes V^{\ast}$ as well as using the double dual isomorphism; this is the most important step), and which concretely is given by

$$\text{End}(V) \ni X \mapsto \left( Y \mapsto \text{tr}(XY) \right) \in \text{End}(V)^{\ast}.$$

It's not entirely clear that these give the same map but you can verify it e.g. by working everything out in terms of a basis of $V$ and the corresponding dual basis of $V^{\ast}$. In terms of such a basis $\{ v_i \}$ and its dual basis $\{ v_i^{\ast} \}$ the first sequence of isomorphisms goes

$$X \mapsto \sum X_{ij} v_i \otimes v_j^{\ast} \mapsto \left( \sum Y_{ij} v_i \otimes v_j^{\ast} \mapsto \sum X_{ij} Y_{ji} \right) \mapsto \left( Y \mapsto \text{tr}(XY) \right)$$

which is the second isomorphism.

It's worth saying precisely that "canonical" here means, among other things, that every map I've written down is $GL(V)$-equivariant.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with infinite-dimensional vector spaces - is there a counterexample to the statement in that setting then?

Comment: @Qizard: if $V$ is countable-dimensional then $\text{End}(V)$ has dimension the cardinality of the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$ and $\text{End}(V)^{\ast}$ has dimension $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.